# WCF: SOAP 1.2 - How do I send an empty header element?

Tags: wcf, soap

I am trying to send data to a SOAP Web Service that adheres to SOAP 1.2 standard and uses certificates for authentication.

I have taken WSDL file and xsd's and generated a WCF Service client.

My issue is now that the XML generated by WCF when a call is made includes a rather lengthy  element that includes numerous security information. According to the documentation for the service the header needs to simply be empty.

```
<soap:Header/>
```

Is there a way to control what WCF will send in terms of headers? I am not well versed in SOAP in general so any advice is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talk about not having any content to the header, then you simply need to use a basicHttpBinding with no security. If you talk specifically about the format of the closed tag then you will need to implement a [custom message encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx) and apply this logic there.